# Is there a way to alter column type in hive table?

Tags: hive, metadata

The current schema is:

```
hive> describe tableA;
OK
id      int
ts      timestamp
```

I want to change `ts` column to be `BIGINT` without dropping table and recreate again. Is it possible?

Comment: Additionally if you are using partitions you must `alter table {table_name} partition column ({column_name} {column_type})`.   Hive can create lots of inconsistency so easily.  Maybe it's me but Hive is very frustrating  :-(

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Found the solution:

```
ALTER TABLE tableA CHANGE ts ts BIGINT AFTER id;
```

See this for complete details: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AlterColumn

Comment: @interskh is there a way to apply this to multiple columns in one statement? such as `ALTER TABLE tableA CHANGE a,b,c a,b,c BIGINT;` I tried separating columns using a comma and it did not work.  Reason I ask is my table was created using the Hue interface for hive and `DECIMAL` defaults to `(10,0)` however I require `(38,0)`

Comment: Do you know if this would also work in case the data is stored as ORC or Parquet?

Comment: DO NOT USE if data is in parquet and you are not at Hive version 1.2. Supposedly this is fixed in Hive 1.2, but my company uses 1.1. I had to delete my table and start over.

Answer (score 35):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE col_name col_name newType
```

Answer (score 16):

It's simple usually to change/modify the exesting table use this syntax in Hive.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE old_col_name new_col_name new_data_type
```

Here you can change  your column name and data type at a time. If you don't want to change col_name simply makes old_col_name and new_col_name are same. Ok.

Come to your problem. If you want to change ts column to be BIGINT.It means column-type you are changing. so simply run this query.

```
ALTER TABLE tableA CHANGE ts ts BIGINT;
```

**Here ts and ts are same, means you are not changing column name, but changing column-type; if you wish to change column name also simply run it.**

```
ALTER TABLE tableA CHANGE ts new_col BIGINT;
```

Now run

```
hive> describe tableA;
OK
id      int
new_col      bigint
```